How to unit test ` software. amazon. awssdk. transfer. s3.model. UploadRequest`
I have code that uses AWS SDK for Java. I call S3TransferManager.upload(UploadRequest) in one of my methods. In a test for this method, I attempt to capture the UploadRequest argument in a mocked version of S3TransferManager and then examine it to determine if the correct content is being sent to S3. Here's the method I'm testing:
public void saveOutputs(Map<String, Long> output) throws JsonProcessingException {
  var now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
  var key = "output.json";
  var content = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(output);
   this.s3TransferManager.upload(UploadRequest.builder()
          .putObjectRequest(PutObjectRequest.builder()
              .bucket(bucketName)
              .key(key)
              .build())
          .requestBody(AsyncRequestBody.fromString(content))
          .build())
      .completionFuture()
      .join();

  log.info("Inventory metrics saved to S3");
}

In the test, I have the following code to capture the uploadRequest parameter. However, I can't seem to get at the request body content to examine it.
    verify(mockTransferManager).upload(uploadRequestCaptor.capture());
    var uploadRequest = uploadRequestCaptor.getValue();
    uploadRequest.requestBody(); // How to convert this to a string so I can examine it?

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Does anyone now how to accomplish this?
